# KeyError in Pandas when passing concatenated string as key

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I have a dataframe 'df' which has column 'Call_ID' with one of the values as '888'. I have following variables:

```
c = 'Call_ID'
v = '888'
q = 'df[c] == v'
```

`df[df[c] == v]` is working fine. However, `df[q]` is giving me key error. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

`df[q]` is looking for a column named `'df[c] == v'`. It is not equivalent to `df[c] == v`, since the first thing is a string and the second thing is a Python expression.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean indexing does *not* support string expressions, nor does it evaluate them.  You'll need `query` instead:

```
df.query('Call_ID == @v')
```

Alternatively,

```
df.query('{} == "{}"'.format(c, v))
```

---

```
df

    a  b  c
0   1  1  a
1   1  2  b
2   1  3  c
6   2  1  d
7   2  2  e
9   2  2  x
10  2  1  x

df.query("c == 'x'") 

    a  b  c
9   2  2  x
10  2  1  x
```

Comment: Using `df.query('{} == "{}"'.format(c, v))` is giving me syntax error

Comment: @Kshitij If it gave you a syntax error, you've obviously copied it wrong, haven't you? As you can see, this works for me.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I was using customized expression as argument to the query. On using `df.query(df.eval(my_exp))` , it worked finally. Thank you for your help :)